# Linux kernel 3.3 power regression

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, power-management

I am using Fedora 16 in my DELL n4110. I recently upgraded the kernel from 3.2 to 3.3. In contradiction to the official claim, my system still drains battery as hell. It only provides 1:30 to 2 hrs of backup under normal stress as before, where as Windows provides 3hrs/+ of backup under similar stress.

Below are some screen shots from `powertop`, stats on the services running in my box and few lines from grub.cfg.

`Overview`
[image]

`Idle stats`
[image]

`Frequency stats`
[image]

`Device stats`
[image]

`tunable`
[image]

`services`

```
/etc/init.d/ceph: ceph conf /etc/ceph/ceph.conf not found; system is not configured.
dc_client.service - SYSV: Distcache is a Distributed SSL Session Cache Client Proxy.
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/dc_client)
      Active: inactive (dead) 
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/dc_client.service
dc_server.service - SYSV: Distcache is a Distributed SSL Session Cache server.
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/dc_server)
      Active: inactive (dead)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/dc_server.service
# Generated by ebtables-save v1.0 on Sat Apr 21 09:35:32 NPT 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server (prefork MPM)
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
      Active: inactive (dead)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service
No active sessions
iscsid.service - LSB: Starts and stops login iSCSI daemon.
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/iscsid)
      Active: active (running) since Sat, 21 Apr 2012 08:11:58 +0545; 1h 23min ago
     Process: 1011 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/iscsid start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 1069 (iscsid)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/iscsid.service
          ├ 1056 iscsiuio
          ├ 1068 iscsid
          └ 1069 iscsid
libvirtd.service - LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/libvirtd)
      Active: active (running) since Sat, 21 Apr 2012 08:11:58 +0545; 1h 23min ago
     Process: 1086 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/libvirtd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 1111 (libvirtd)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/libvirtd.service
          ├ 1111 libvirtd --daemon
          └ 1183 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces...
started
No open transaction
netconsole module not loaded
Configured devices:
lo Auto_ADW-4401 Auto_PROLiNK_H5004N Auto_korky p4p1
Currently active devices:
lo p4p1 virbr0
radvd.service - router advertisement daemon for IPv6
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/radvd.service; disabled)
      Active: inactive (dead)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/radvd.service
sandbox is running
svnserve.service - LSB: start and stop the svnserve daemon
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/svnserve)
      Active: inactive (dead)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/svnserve.service
```

`grub.cfg`

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Fedora (3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2260640d-2901-49e4-b14f-bf9addb04eb7
    echo 'Loading Fedora (3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64)'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_machine-lv_root ro pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 rd.lvm.lv=vg_machine/lv_root rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=vg_machine/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd /initramfs-3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64.img
}
menuentry 'Fedora (3.3.1-3.fc16.x86_64)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2260640d-2901-49e4-b14f-bf9addb04eb7
    echo 'Loading Fedora (3.3.1-3.fc16.x86_64)'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.3.1-3.fc16.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_machine-lv_root ro pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 rd.lvm.lv=vg_machine/lv_root rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=vg_machine/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd /initramfs-3.3.1-3.fc16.x86_64.img
}
```

Is this normal? Are there still problems with power consumption in 3.3?

`Is there any way to report this problem to the official kernel group???`

Comment: This depends on far, far more than just the linux version. I'd rather say that merely upgrading your kernel has very little chances of significantly changing your battery drain. You need to investigate the issue with proper tools like `powertop` rather than just upgrade your kernel.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Battery drain might be related to the kernel, for example if some driver doesn't put a peripheral in the right mode or is missing the firmware that would handle power saving.

Comment: is there any solution to this???

Comment: can you decrease screen brightness a little bit, try another DE as well - like LXDE

Comment: @jet i've tried all other light weight shells, even tried decreasing the screen birghtness, nth worked for me and my fan pumps out heat as if it can cook my hand

Comment: Power consumption on linux is a major issue, it always has been.
There's no need to file a bug report for this.

Comment: @nikhil well not always, it started with linux 2.6.38 and should have ended at 3.3, jus a small contribution to the community to make linux better

Comment: I hope you're right. That is probably the killer feature for people who use their PCs on the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone with new versions of linux kernel :). I have not seen power regression since ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/reporting-bugs.html), which should also be in the kernel source you used to compile 3.3 ...

If you are totally stumped as to whom to send the report, send it to
linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org. (For more information on the linux-kernel
mailing list see http://www.tux.org/lkml/).